# Excel VBA copy folder, move all files - but if file exists skip

Tags: vba, database, file, fso

I am trying to create a backup database on a network drive using fso.folder copy. My intention is to move all files within the folder, but if a file already exists on the backup drive, skip it, and copy the remainder of the files in the folder. I currently have

```
SourceFileName="C:\users\desktop\test1"
DestinFileName="C:\users\desktop\test2"

FSO.copyfolder Source:=Sourcefilename, Destination:=Destinfilename, OverwriteFiles:= False
```

However, the script errors when it finds the existing file. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Files Without Overwriting

- I would recommend the first solution. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method) is 'somewhat leading you on' (at least me) to use the second solution. It's up to you to find out if the second one is maybe more efficient. You cannot apply `On Error` on the `folder part`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFilesNoOverwrite()
    
    Const srcFolderPath As String = "C:\users\desktop\test1"
    Const dstFolderPath As String = "C:\users\desktop\test2"
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(srcFolderPath) Then
            MsgBox "Source Folder doesn't exist.", vbCritical, "No Source"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If .FolderExists(dstFolderPath) Then
            Dim Sep As String: Sep = Application.PathSeparator
            Dim fsoFile As Object
            Dim FilePath As String
            For Each fsoFile In .GetFolder(srcFolderPath).Files
                FilePath = dstFolderPath & Sep & fsoFile.Name
                If Not .FileExists(FilePath) Then
                    .CopyFile _
                        Source:=fsoFile.Path, _
                        Destination:=FilePath
                End If
            Next fsoFile
        Else
            .CopyFolder _
                Source:=srcFolderPath, _
                Destination:=dstFolderPath
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub copyFilesNoOverwriteOnError()
    
    Const srcFolderPath As String = "C:\users\desktop\test1"
    Const dstFolderPath As String = "C:\users\desktop\test2"
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(srcFolderPath) Then
            MsgBox "Source Folder doesn't exist.", vbCritical, "No Source"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If .FolderExists(dstFolderPath) Then
            Dim Sep As String: Sep = Application.PathSeparator
            Dim fsoFile As Object
            For Each fsoFile In .GetFolder(srcFolderPath).Files
                On Error Resume Next
                .CopyFile _
                    Source:=fsoFile.Path, _
                    Destination:=dstFolderPath & Sep & fsoFile.Name, _
                    OverwriteFiles:=False
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next fsoFile
        Else
            .CopyFolder _
                Source:=srcFolderPath, _
                Destination:=dstFolderPath
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first one is the most sensical. Is there a way to add a loop within the Folder exists path to copy all subfolders and check within those as well?